# Why when I click left the editor type is opening?

Tags: interface

I'm a newbie on Blender, this is my first really doing something on it. I don't really know how but I changed the interface in a way that I didn't want to and tried to change it like it was at the origin but it didn't work.

Suddenly when I click left a window popped, it was the editor type. I don't know how I change it but I can't change it back to was it was before. I can only type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + left click and drag so it will select (like if we only left click before).

I try to reinstall Blender but that didn't change anything...

[image: screenshot]

ps: I'm not English so maybe it's something really easy to resolve but I really don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of your Blender?

Comment: sure ! don't know if this helpful but this is what i get when i left click (and will change the view whenever i do that...)

Comment: To get Blenders UI and all settings back to how they were when you first opened Blender, go to the:    File menu > Defaults > Load factory Settings > and then you will see a little pop_up asking you to,    "OK, Restore factory Settings"    which you will need to click on to validate this operation.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Your welcome :) I would guess that everyone who has ever tried learning Blender has needed at some time or other to "Restore Factory Settings" lol.